# c# winforms datagridview checkbox - increase clickable area to entire column width

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

I have searched and found no solution that works for my problem, so here's my situation:

I have a `datagridview` in WinForms and want the entire cell that contains a checkbox to cause the box to be checked/unchecked. Currently, I must click exactly within the checkbox itself.

I don't want my users to have to play "checkbox sniper".  it's just annoying.

Thanks
-Michele

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that there is some direct way, but you can handle [DataGridView.CellClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick(v=vs.110).aspx) event:

```
private void dataGridView_CellClick(object sender,
    DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;

    if (!(dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn))
         return;

    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
        dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

    cell.Value = !(Boolean)cell.Value;
}
```

But there is one gotcha:

> For clicks in a DataGridViewCheckBoxCell, this event occurs before the
>   check box changes value, so if you do not want to calculate the
>   expected value based on the current value, you will typically handle
>   the DataGridView.CellValueChanged event instead.

So, to avoid unpleasant effects you will have also to handle [DataGridView.CellValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) and use some flag to detect whether the change is caused by normal check or by CellClick event handler.

Comment: That's what I'd tend to do.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand why you are referring to DataGridViewImageCell at all... haven't been doing this for long

Comment: That's a minor mistake (code has been reworked from MSDN example). Will fix it now.

Answer (score 0):

first get the cell clicked event follow this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). on that you can right your checkbox.checked code.
[this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) tutorial is also good,get the right cell and check your checkbox over there